# what kind of 'select' in ms sql server store procedure will be returned to dataset in c# code?

Tags: sql-server

for example: 
here is a store procedure:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 'x' 
    FROM billable_acct_payout (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE i_billable_acct_id = @i_billable_acct_id
)
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'PayoutInfo'          as 'TableName'
            ,ba.i_billable_acct_id   as 'BillableAcctId' 
...
```

just as above,when I call this store procedure and receive the data returned in c# code like this:

```
DataSet ds = new Dataset();
DataAdapter da...
da.Fill(ds);
```

Now I know that the first 'select' in 'IF EXISTS' will not return to my dataset,but the second 'select' do.

the question is,how to know whether the 'select' in store procedure will return to dataset or not?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to execute the stored procedure in the Management Studio and see what's returned.

As a rule of thumb, the following (maybe incomplete) list of selects will not return anything to C#:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT ...)

SELECT TOP 1 @variable = Field FROM ...

SET @variable = (SELECT TOP 1 Field FROM ...)

INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...

... WHERE Field IN (SELECT ...)

... WHERE Field = (SELECT TOP 1 ...)

DECLARE ... CURSOR FOR SELECT ...
```

One could say that every `SELECT`, the results of which are not consumed by a surrounding statement or the stored procedure itself is returned to the caller.

Comment: "Please note that if the stored procedure returns more than one result set, only the first one can be used in C#." - that's not actually true. See MARS

Comment: Maybe only the first can be used to automatically fill a data set via an adapter, but it's certainly possible to consume multiple result sets from C# in general. See [`SqlDataReader.NextResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult.aspx)

Comment: On MARS: The documentation says *In previous versions, only one batch could be executed at a time against a single connection.*. So I presume this is only possible with .NET 4.5?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I was under the impression that `NextResult` returned only the next row of the result set, not another result set from a set of result sets?

Comment: I want to know which results will be returned immediately when I am watch a store procedure itself..I think there must be some rules..

Comment: @matrixit I know what you want. My answer would be "every standalone select statement", but then your next question would be "what do you mean by standalone?" and I'd have to say "statements that are not one of the above".

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - see the remarks section of the page I linked to: "Used to process multiple results, which can be generated by executing batch Transact-SQL statements.". `Read` is the method that advances to the next row in the current result set.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Ah, see? You learn something every day :-) I actually didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

If you got data then the stored procedure returned data to your dataset.

But in general you should think about to change that kind of stored procedures. I just did performance tests on a mssql 2000, and I think most of the results are still valid.

For example it was way faster to let a stored procedure write its results into a table and query these result table. That would be my advise to you, change your stored procedure, add a unique key as parameter and use these parameter to find your results in your results table.